# HTML5 video with javascript - custom buttons for multiple videos

Tags: javascript, html, video

I'm using the code found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh924823(v=vs.85).aspx), which I've hacked a bit to get rid of the volume buttons, etc. What I want to do is have about 8 videos that each autoplay, loop, and have buttons for changing the speed of the playback. How can I modify this code so that it works for an arbitrary number of video elements, do I have give multiple variables to the init() function or something?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Full player example</title>
    <!-- Uncomment the following meta tag if you have issues rendering this page on an intranet or local site. -->    
    <!-- <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/> -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function init() {        // Master function, encapsulates all functions
            var video = document.getElementById("Video1");                                               
            if (video.canPlayType) {   // tests that we have HTML5 video support
                document.getElementById("buttonbar").style.display = "block";                
                video.src == "";
                function vidplay(evt) {
                    if (video.src == "") {  // inital source load
                        getVideo();
                    }
                    button = evt.target; //  get the button id to swap the text based on the state                                    
                    if (video.paused) {   // play the file, and display pause symbol
                        video.play();
                        button.textContent = "||";
                    } else {              // pause the file, and display play symbol  
                        video.pause();
                        button.textContent = ">";
                    }
                }
                //  load video file from input field
                function getVideo() {
                    var fileURL = "/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=experiment_log_books:sig0700.mp4";  // get input field                    
                    if (fileURL != "") {
                        video.src = fileURL;
                        video.load();  // if HTML source element is used
                        document.getElementById("play").click();  // start play
                    } else {
                        errMessage("Enter a valid video URL");  // fail silently
                    }
                }

                //  skip forward, backward, or restart
                function setTime(tValue) {
                    try {
                        if (tValue == 0) {
                            video.currentTime = tValue;
                        }
                        else {
                            video.currentTime += tValue;
                        }

                     } catch (err) {
                         // errMessage(err) // show exception
                     errMessage("Video content might not be loaded");
                       }
             }
                //  display an error message 
                function errMessage(msg) {
                // displays an error message for 5 seconds then clears it
                    document.getElementById("errorMsg").textContent = msg;
                    setTimeout("document.getElementById('errorMsg').textContent=''", 5000);
                }
                //  Play
                document.getElementById("play").addEventListener("click", vidplay, false);
                //  Restart
                document.getElementById("restart").addEventListener("click", function () {
                    setTime(0);
                }, false);
                //  Skip backward 10 seconds
                document.getElementById("rew").addEventListener("click", function () {
                    setTime(-10);
                }, false);
                //  Skip forward 10 seconds
                document.getElementById("fwd").addEventListener("click", function () {
                    setTime(10);
                }, false);
                //  set src == latest video file URL
                document.getElementById("loadVideo").addEventListener("click", getVideo, false);

                // fail with message 
                video.addEventListener("error", function (err) {
                    errMessage(err);
                }, true);

                // playback speed buttons
                document.getElementById("slower").addEventListener("click", function () {
                    video.playbackRate -= .25;
                }, false);
                document.getElementById("faster").addEventListener("click", function () {
                    video.playbackRate += .25;
                }, false);
                document.getElementById("normal").addEventListener("click", function () {
                    video.playbackRate = 1;
                }, false);

document.getElementById("play").click();
            } // end of runtime
        }// end of master         
    </script>

    </head>
    <body onload="init();" >        

    <video id="Video1" controls autoplay loop height="320" width="640" title="Sig 0700">            
         HTML5 Video is required for this example
    </video>

    <div id="buttonbar" style="display: none;")>
        <button id="restart" title="Restart button">[]</button> 
        <button id="slower" title="Slower playback button">-</button> 
        <button id="rew" title="Rewind button" >&lt;&lt;</button>
        <button id="play" title="Play button">&gt;</button>
        <button id="fwd" title="Forward button" >&gt;&gt;</button>
        <button id="faster" title="Faster playback button">+</button>
        <button id="normal" title="Reset playback rate button">=</button>        
    </div>    
    <div id= "inputField" style="display:none;" >
        <label>Type or paste a video URL: <br/>
        <input type="text" id="videoFile" style="width: 300px;"  title="video file input field" value="http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/ieblog/2011/nov/pp4_blog_demo.mp4" />        
        <button id="loadVideo" title="Load video button" >Load</button>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div title="Error message area" id="errorMsg" style="color:Red;"></div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want that all the videos are synchronized ?

Comment: No. Individual controls for each.

Comment: So all videos at the same time, at the same page?

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways this can be achieved but since you want it to work for an arbitrary number of videos I would put the creation of the markup and binding of the controls into a function that accepts the video url as an argument, something like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Full player example</title>
    <!-- Uncomment the following meta tag if you have issues rendering this page on an intranet or local site. -->    
    <!-- <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/> -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.videos = 0;
        function createVideo (src) {
            var container = document.createElement('div'),
                    video = document.createElement('video'),
                    buttonContainer = document.createElement('div'),
                    faster = document.createElement('button'),
                    forward = document.createElement('button'),
                    normal = document.createElement('button'),
                    playPause = document.createElement('button'),
                    restart = document.createElement('button'),
                    rewind = document.createElement('button'),
                    slower = document.createElement('button'),
                    error = document.createElement('div'),
                    showError = function (message) {
                        error.textContent = message;
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            error.textContent = '';
                        }, 5000);
                    };

            ++window.videos;

            document.body.appendChild(container);
            container.id = 'container-' + window.videos;

            container.appendChild(video);
            video.id = 'video-' + window.videos;
            video.autoplay = true;
            video.controls = true;
            video.loop = true;
            video.src = src;
            video.load();

            video.addEventListener('error', function (err) {
                showError(err);
            }, true);

            container.appendChild(buttonContainer);
            buttonContainer.id = 'buttonContainer-' + window.videos;

            buttonContainer.appendChild(restart);
            buttonContainer.appendChild(slower);
            buttonContainer.appendChild(rewind);
            buttonContainer.appendChild(playPause);
            buttonContainer.appendChild(forward);
            buttonContainer.appendChild(faster);
            buttonContainer.appendChild(normal);

            faster.id = 'faster-' + window.videos;
            faster.textContent = '+';
            faster.title = 'Faster playback button';
            faster.addEventListener('click', function () {
                video.playbackRate += .25;
            }, false);

            forward.id = 'forward-' + window.videos;
            forward.textContent = '>>';
            forward.title = 'Forward button';
            forward.addEventListener('click', function () {
                video.currentTime += 10;
            }, false);

            normal.id = 'normal-' + window.videos;
            normal.textContent = '=';
            normal.title = 'Reset playback rate button';
            normal.addEventListener('click', function () {
                video.playbackRate = 1;
            }, false);

            playPause.id = 'playPause-' + window.videos;
            playPause.textContent = '||';
            playPause.title = 'Play button';
            playPause.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
                button = evt.target;
                if (video.paused) {
                    video.play();
                    button.textContent = '||';
                }
                else {
                    video.pause();
                    button.textContent = '>';
                }
            }, false);

            restart.id = 'restart-' + window.videos;
            restart.textContent = '[]';
            restart.title = 'Restart button';
            restart.addEventListener('click', function () {
                video.currentTime = 0;
            }, false);

            rewind.id = 'rewind-' + window.videos;
            rewind.textContent = '<<';
            rewind.title = 'Rewind button';
            rewind.addEventListener('click', function () {
                video.currentTime -= 10;
            }, false);

            slower.id = 'slower-' + window.videos;
            slower.textContent = '-';
            slower.title = 'Slower playback button';
            slower.addEventListener('click', function () {
                video.playbackRate -= .25;
            }, false);

            container.appendChild(error);
            error.id = 'error-' + window.videos;
            error.title = 'Error message area';
            error.style.color = 'red';
        };

        function init() {
            createVideo('/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=experiment_log_books:sig0700.mp4');
            createVideo('/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=experiment_log_books:sig0700.mp4');
        }
    </script>

    </head>
    <body onload="init();"></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I haven't time to get it to work now, but I'll mark the answer as accepted for the bounty before it expires.